# Login Session Data Not Persisting In Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, session-cookies

I am implementing a user authentication system in Ruby on Rails following this tutorial [Building a Simple Session Based Authentication using Ruby on Rails](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-simple-session-based-authentication-using-ruby-on-rails-9tah3y4j).

I think I did everything as explained in the article, but I could not get the `user_id` to be persisted across page refresh after a successful login.

**This is the log_in method**

```
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

After I successfully logged in, I checked if the user id was saved in the session by printing out `p session[:user_id]` it returns `nil`

Answer (score 1):

After spending the day trying out various suggestions from others, I finally discovered that my browser was actually blocking the `session` from persisting.

I changed my browser to another one and everything worked like magic.